# Restrict certain actions to plugin-specific admin menu pages only

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, admin-menu

I'm working on a plugin and want to restrict some things to my plugin-specific admin menu pages only. Therefore, I write the slugs being returned when adding (sub)menu pages into an array so I can check later on the current page against it.

The problem seems to be that `get_current_screen` is returning **`null`** when called from/before `admin_init`. I add the menu pages, however, hooked to `admin_menu` - which is before `admin_init`.

Here is the **not working** code:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_admin_menu' );
function my_admin_menu() {
    // Set up plugin admin menu
    $menu_pages = array();
    $menu_pages[] = add_menu_page( ... );
    $menu_pages[] = add_submenu_page( ... );

    $screen = get_current_screen(); // UNFORTUNATELY, $screen is null here
    $screen = $screen->id;
    foreach ( $menu_pages as $page ) if ( $screen === $page ) {
        // Do plugin-specific stuff
    }
} // function my_admin_menu
```

So, do I really have to store the pages array in a way that I can access it later in a function hooked somewhere after `admin_init`? I thought about just using the page slugs where I defined the pages and then forget about it.

As toscho pointed out, one may use the *slugs* as hooks (what they actually are):

```
$page = add_menu_page( ... );
add_action( $page, ... );
```

However, when in need of the **current screen**, that hook is located too early in the chain, so one could/should use `add_action( 'load-' . $page, ...);` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slug returned by `add_menu_page()` is the name of an action.

```
foreach ( $menu_pages as $action )
    add_action( $action, "callback_handler" );
```

See the comments in my demo plugin [T5 Admin Menu Demo](https://github.com/toscho/T5-Admin-Menu-Demo).